# Php function exec() is needed for TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3-7.6.x

Any one explain me `exec()` function is needed for TYPO3?

If yes than describe in which typo3 functionality depends on this function. if i have disable this function then what happening in typo3? which functionality will not work after disable this function...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

[A single search for "shell_exec" on typo3's source code](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=shell_exec&type=Code) finds two potential matches :

- [SpellCheckingController.php](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/015f3bdae52c0e6e03f351fd49c293b201d78bc8/typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/Classes/Controller/SpellCheckingController.php), which calls [Aspell](http://aspell.net/) functions, for spell checking purposes for the htmlArea RTE extension
- [Scheduler.php](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/d478cbe9955011c9fa50c0c1eeabaa8c0f181a63/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php) calls Unix `at` and `atrm` functions

So, these are not vital functionalities, but you may have to disable manually the spell checker for your textareas (As I understand [in the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/Configuration/PageTsconfig/interfaceConfiguration/Index.html)).
As for the scheduler, it won't cause any problem if you don't intend to use it.

Comment: So, If i disable this function. it's not effected another typo3 functionality. Right?

Comment: Seems not. But why do you want to disable it in the first place?

Comment: If you don't intend on uploading another code which could use this function, it's safe to keep it : the implementations listed above seem to be intrusion proof

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which `exec` function you disable you might loose the possibility to use the mighty tool ImageMagic/GraphicsMagic for resizing and modifying images. It is not vital, but restrict you or your editors in using images.